# cmake : no such file or directory when compiling

Tags: c++, cmake

using cmake to generate a static libary and link it in main.c. Here is directory hireachy:

```
├─.vscode
├─bin
└─mymathlib
    ├─include
    ├─lib
    └─src
    └─CMakeLists.txt
├─main.c
├─CMakeLists.txt
```

in main.c, I include a header file located in mymathlib/include

```
#include "mymath.h"
```

but it follows a error : mymath.h : no such file or directory

I use include_directories() in both CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists(top level)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(CALCULATOR)
include_directories(mymathlib/include)
add_subdirectory(mymathlib)
add_executable(calculator ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c)
target_link_libraries(calculator myamth)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_compile_options(-Wall -g)
```

CMakeLists(in /mymathlib)

```
project(MyMathLib)
include_directories(include)
aux_source_directory(src SRCS)
add_library(mymath STATIC ${SRCS})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH lib)
```

I think include_directories() is enough for this problem, but it seems not.
How to fix this ? THX :)

Comment: Please update your question with the verbose build output.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Assuming you have the file at `mymathlib/include/mymath.h` relatively to your project's top level directory, you shouldn't get given error.